# Errors using same port on different machines

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have written an application ( called M2 ) which reads data arriving on one port, processes it, then sends the results out to another port.

If I choose to send data to 193.168.1.101:5001 everything works.

If I send to 192.168.1.101:5001 it does not.  Why should changing the first byte of the IP address make any difference?

The reason for the change is that when I trasmit a packet to 193.168.1.101:5001 then it takes about a millisecond, but when I transmit to 192.168.1.101:5001 it takes over a second.  This thousand-fold change in timing messes up everything else in my program - in particular reader starvation sets in and I start losing input packets.

What would cause such a drastic change in transmission time?  Note that the transmission does not fail, it just takes an extremely long time.

Comment: I concur with folks over networking. What you are saying is not a network issue, and is simply not possible. IP address as a whole is used, not first 3 octets.

Comment: Could you give an example of the "all kinds of horrible errors when I do this" ?

Comment: can you ping the target machine?

Comment: @ZabojCampula The input data received is garbage, and the output data never arrives at the destination

Comment: @FelicePollano The client can.  Both the client and I receive garbage when using 192.168.1.101:5001 -> M2 -> 192.168.1.200:5001

Comment: I smell Undefined Behaviour. Post a selfcontained example.

Comment: @sehe complete self-contained program demostrating problem posted

Comment: Looking at it now. Fixed my streaming setup: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: Wait. If the address is the same you end up sending yourself packets. Is that the intent?

Comment: @sehe Damn!  That is a typo.  Should have been 192.168.1.200:5001

Comment: The small test synchronous program does NOT show the problems ( once I fix the typo ).  The big, asynchronous program still shows the problem, so I will have to try and track it down there.  I am going to be busy this weekend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95742/discussion-between-sehe-and-ravenspoint).

Answer (score 0):

The address 192.168.1.101:5001 is extremely slow ( around 2 seconds to transmit a packet ) compared to 193.168.1.101:5001 ( about 1 millisecond ).  Since the transmitter was using synchronous sends, the input was starved of CPU and so input packets were dropped.

I changed the the output transmitter to asynchronous operation, with a deadline timer to limit the amount of time spent on attempting to transmit a packet. This solved the input starvation.  I used code based on this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_udp_client.cpp

I am still curious why one address would be a thousand times slower than another.  The bad address is on the same subnet ( is that the correct term? ) as the transmitting computer, so perhaps that has something to do with it?